# Is there a surjection $f:[0,1]^{\omega} \to [0,1]$ such that the set of points that have non-unique primages is a null set in $[0,1]$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\Bbb H = [0,1]^{\omega}$, $\pi_i$ is the canonical projection that sends a sequence of elements in $[0,1]$ to its $i$th coordinate. The Borel structure $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ and probability measure $P$ of $[0,1]$ is given. Is there a surjection $f:\Bbb H \to [0,1]$ such that there is a set $A$ satisfies:

- The restriction $f| {\Bbb H} \setminus A \to [0,1]$ is a bijection.
- $f(A)$ is a null subset of $[0,1]$.
- For all finite subset $F \subset \Bbb N$ and $j \in F$, $B_j \in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$, $P(f(\bigcap_{j \in F}\pi_j^{-1}(B_j)))= \prod_{j \in F}{P(f(\pi_j^{-1}(B_j)))}$

**Motivation**: It is known that contructing the probability space of an infinite sequence of fair coin tossing doesn't need to revoke Kolmogorov extension theorem, once we recognize that the inverse of binary expansion $f:2^{\omega} \to [0,1]$ admits that points that have  non-unique primages forms a null set in $[0,1]$. I want to know whether we can use a similar method for the situation that tossing a different unfair coin at stage $n$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: What kind of $f$ are you looking for? Your spaces are Borel isomorphic.

Comment: @hot_queen, My bad, I forget to add the independence condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To model a sequence of independent tosses with probabilities $(p_n)_{n\geqslant1}$, one can send each $x=(x_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ in $2^\omega$ to $f(x)$ in $[0,1]$ defined as follows.

First, for every finite word $w$ of length $n$, define $h(w)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^np_k^{w_k}q_k^{1-w_k}$, where $q_k=1-p_k$. Second, consider the lexicographic order $\prec$ on finite words of the same length. Third, define $g(w)=\sum\limits_{v\prec w}h(v)$ where the sum is over every finite word $v$ of the same length as $w$ such that $v\prec w$. Finally, let $f(x)$ denote the limit of $g(x^n)$ when $n\to\infty$, where each $x^n$ is the finite prefix of $x$ of length $n$.

A recursive definition of $g$ is as follows. One sets $g(0)=q_1$ and $g(1)=1$, then $g(w1)=g(w)$ and $g(w0)=g(w)-h(w1)$ for every word $w$ of length $k$ (alternative initialization is $g(\varnothing)=1$ where $\varnothing$ is the empty word).

Then, for every word $w$ of finite length $n$, $g(w)$ is the probability to observe any word $\prec w$ in $n$  tosses with probabilities $(p_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$.

For every word $w$ of finite length, $f(w01^\infty)=g(w0)=g(w)-h(w1)$. On the other hand, for every $k\geqslant0$,  $g(w10^{k+1})=g(w10^k)-h(w10^k1)$. Iterating this, one gets 
$$
f(w10^\infty)=g(w1)-\sum\limits_{k\geqslant0}h(w10^k1)=g(w)-h(w1)s(w),
$$ 
where, considering the length $n$ of $w$,
$$
s(w)=\sum\limits_{k\geqslant0}p_{n+k+2}\prod\limits_{i=1}^kq_{n+1+i}=\sum\limits_{k\geqslant0}(1-q_{n+k+2})\prod\limits_{i=1}^kq_{n+1+i}=1-\prod\limits_{i\geqslant1}q_{n+1+i}.
$$
If the series $\sum\limits_ip_i$ diverges, the last product is zero hence $s(w)=1$ and $f(w01^\infty)=f(w10^\infty)$ for every finite word $w$. These are countably elements in $2^\omega$. My guess is that these are the only cases when different elements $x$ and $y$ yield $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir. Could you please give some details on why "non-unique pre-images correspond to terminating expansions"?

Comment: Do you know which numbers have two *binary* classical expansions?

Comment: I guess I know. The eventually constant sequences.

Comment: Well... exactly the same applies.

Comment: Hope you don't mind. I still can't get it. It seems to me that if we want $f((1, 0, 0, \ldots)) = f((0,1,1,1 \ldots))$,we have to ensure $p_1 = (1-p_1)(\sum_{j>1}(\prod_{2\leq k \leq j}p_k))$, which is impossible since  $p_i$ is arbitary.

Comment: Hmmm... Good point. Rereading my answer, I get the impression it is just rubbish. Sorry about that (I will delete it soon).

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not deleting, finally.